# Filling column with formula with no variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm struggling with a problem here. I'm sure it's so simples, that's why I can't find the answer.

I need to apply this to `Sheet1!C4:C22`:

```
=(RANDBETWEEN(1.45*100,1.95*100)/100)+Sheet2!C12
```

Problem is: I've tried Fill tool && select the range `Sheet1!C4:C22`, paste the formula in the bar and hit ctrl+enter but here lies the problem: excel keeps changing the cell on the formula, as it goes down the column. I don't want that! How can I stop it doing that without copy paste by hand? I know it's not a lot of columns, but it's handy.

P.S: `Sheet2!C12` contains a fixed value of `0.056`.

Comment: Is this what you are trying? `Sheet2!C12` to `Sheet2!$C$12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a constant range when dragging a formula down then add `$` dollar signs before the letter and number

example

```
Sheet1!$C$12
```

Comment: I know. New account (I've been leeching a lot on the past, especially regarding Java & C), so apparently I have to wait X minutes before stating that it solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help